# How to show/hide component on button click/hover in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm implementing a toolbar where each route (nav buttons) I hover on will display a popover, similar to bootstrap, containing the component I send (kind of like the navbar items [here](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/argon-design-system)).

```
<div *ngFor="let route of toolbarRoutes">
  <button mat-stroked-button class="toolbar-nav-button" (click)="routeTo(route.path)">
    {{route.displayName}}
  </button>
  <app-hoverable *ngIf="route.component" [component]="route.component"></app-hoverable>
</div>
```

My problem is that I want to render/show `app-hoverable` only if the button (`<button mat-stroked-button class="toolbar-nav-button" (click)="routeTo(route.path)">`) is hovered, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply like this (I have stacked attributes for readability) :

```
<div *ngFor="let route of toolbarRoutes">
  <button mat-stroked-button
    class="toolbar-nav-button"
    (click)="routeTo(route.path)"
    (mouseenter)="route.showHoverable=true"
    (mouseleave)="route.showHoverable=false">

        {{route.displayName}}
  </button>

  <app-hoverable *ngIf="route.showHoverable" [component]="route.component"></app-hoverable>

</div>
```